# How to burn a burn folder from Applescript

Tags: applescript

I've written an AppleScript script which creates a burn folder and copies aliases for the files I want to burn to the CD/DVD in that folder.  It works well.  What I'd like the script to do next is actually start the burn process.  It's OK if I get prompted to insert a disk.

How do you get AppleScript to start the burn process?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

May be the with Automator.app included action "Burn a Disc" could help you. It's under "Utilities".

ADDITION

I just did a `man -k burn` in Terminal and it showed a console utility named `drutil -- interact with CD/DVD burners`. That looks like it would do the trick*

*(it's easy to call any console utility with the `do shell script` command)*

Comment: How do you script that action from AppleScript?

Comment: I don't know, sorry: but I added something else to the answer.

Comment: You already have my +1, but kudos for use of `man -k` (equivalent to `apropros`).

Comment: Not tested, but try this: `do shell script "drutil burn -noverify -eject " & quoted form of POSIX path of <your:burn:folder>`